# how to resolve StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in android

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my logcat report:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=2
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
at com.buzzador.profile.getValidPhoneNumber(profile.java:1966)
at com.buzzador.profile.setDataForServer(profile.java:1717)
at com.buzzador.profile$5.onClick(profile.java:236)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and i think the issue is in this function:

```
public String getValidPhoneNumber (String phoneNumber, String country)
{
    String csValidPhoneNumber = "";

    phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberWithoutReqularExpresions(phoneNumber);
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst ("^0*", "");

    String csCountryCode = getCountryCode(country);

    String csAppendedCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, csCountryCode.length());
    if(csAppendedCode.equals(csCountryCode))
    {
        csValidPhoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber;
        return csValidPhoneNumber;
    }

    csValidPhoneNumber = "+" + csCountryCode + phoneNumber;

    return csValidPhoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: Which line is `profile.java:1966` in your code?

Comment: @Kevinrob this is the 'profile.java:1966' line String csAppendedCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, csCountryCode.length());

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you sure that `phoneNumber` is not equal to `""`?
You have to check that `phoneNumber` have more chars than the `csCountryCode.length()`.

```
String csAppendedCode = phoneNumber.length() > csCountryCode.length() ? phoneNumber.substring(0, csCountryCode.length()) : "";
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. To check for `phoneNumber != "";`

Answer (score 1):

The last index of a `String` is `string.length()-1` but you are trying to access index with `string.length()` which doesn't exist, that's why you are getting this exception...

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=2
```

Now, you should change this line...

```
String csAppendedCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, csCountryCode.length());
```

to this...

```
String csAppendedCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, csCountryCode.length()-1);
```

Comment: Not a valid answer always!!! what if `csCountryCode` length is greater than `phoneNumber` length?

Comment: the `length()` always returns `lastindex+1` value, so when you will try to access last index of a `String` with `lastIndex+1` then you will always get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Once try this `String string = "Android"; System.out.println(string.substring(0, string.length()));`... Does not throw any Exception...

Comment: @HamidShatu No. Read the java APIs: *substring(int start, int end): Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring* ***begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1***. Your answer is wrong.