# app crashes when changing the font style of the device

Tags: android, font-face, samsung-mobile

I am facing a issue in Samsung mobile, the issue is this, i open the application that i have made and minimized the app now the app is running at the background, now i go to my mobile

> settings-->Display--> font style,

Then i changed the font when i come back and open the app that was running at the back ground the app crashes

I do not know where the issue is can you please give some idea on how to move about

This was the `error` that i was able to see in my `logcat`

> 2-12 17:58:54.883 1473-1473/com.mysmcc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.mysmcc, PID: 1473 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysmcc/com.mysmcc.activities.AppMainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500) at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494) at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:209) at com.mysmcc.activities.AppMainActivity.onCreate(AppMainActivity.java:213) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: where is your **`CODE`**.??

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to resolve StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955414/how-to-resolve-stringindexoutofboundsexception-in-android)

Comment: Please show code of `com.mysmcc.activities.AppMainActivity` and your used xml layout.

Comment: Hi all, I tried to paste my code which is big and cannot be uploaded what to do ?